# What medium is the bacteria used to synthesize B12 sourced from?

Tags: biochemistry, bacteriology, biotechnology, biosynthesis

Would that be from water, soil, plants, funguses,...?

I [asked the question](https://www.quora.com/Where-are-the-bacterias-used-to-make-vegan-vitamin-B12-supplements-obtained-from?new_question=True#) in Quora but that, at the time of posting in this forum, haven't been very helpful. I also have searched for the information, but I haven't been able to find it. [In Vegan Health](http://veganhealth.org/b12/vegansources) it says that

> "The vitamin B12 component in B12 supplements and fortified foods is
>   made by bacteria and sourced from bacteria cultures; it is not taken
>   from animal products"

But I wonder where did those cultures come from. One day someone had to collect the bacteria from somewhere in order to start the cultures.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The geographical location from which the bacteria were originally obtained from?

Comment: @canadianer I'm asking what medium is the bacteria used to synthesize B12 sourced from -water, animal intestines, plants, soil, feces.